# In <img> tag how to load a byte formatted data

Tags: html, typescript

Could I proceed with byte data for binding in  tag in HTML5

```
        **<img id="mainImage" src="{{imageVisible ? droppedImage: firtsImageToBind}}" class="imagepics" alt="loading..." />**

        <!--<img *ngIf="zoomImageVisible" src="{{zoomedImage}}">-->

        <div class="top_left_corner_data">

        </div>
        <div class="top_right_corner_data">

        </div>
        <div class="bottom_left_corner_data">

        </div>
        <div class="bottom_right_corner_data">

        </div>**strong text**
```

my ts file is attached below

```
callRawProjection(event: MouseEvent, srcImg: any): void {

    document.getElementById('dropId').style.cursor = "default";

    console.log(srcImg.droppedImage);
    console.log(srcImg.firtsImageToBind);

    for (var a = 0; a < this.rawProjectionList.length; a++) {

        if (srcImg.droppedImage === this.rawProjectionList[a].imageURL || srcImg.firtsImageToBind === this.rawProjectionList[a].imageURL) {

            var objectId = this.rawProjectionList[a].rawProjectionID;
            var seriesUID = this.rawProjectionList[a].seriesInstanceUID

            //When click thumbnail image their corresponding original image should bind
            var url = 'http://mediotrenderingservice-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/wado?requestType=wado&studyUID=63&seriesUID=' + seriesUID + '&ObjectUID=' + objectId + '&rows=512&columns=512';
            this.http.get(url)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => {
                    console.log(data.DCMImageBuffer);
                    this.zoomImageVisible = true;
                    var binaryData = data.DCMImageBuffer;
                    console.log(binaryData);
                    this.zoomedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64' + data.DCMImageBuffer;
                    this.droppedImage = this.zoomedImage;
                    console.log(this.droppedImage);

                }, (err) => console.error(err),
                () => console.log('done')
                );
        }
    }




}
```

My byte data that to bind is given below

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

Pease provide any solution....to bind this raw data into UI.

Comment: What's your image format?

Comment: the above given data is byte format

Comment: and i want to convert this data into .jpg image format

Comment: to bind in UI with img tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, YourImageData" />
```

Paste your image data at `YourImageData`.

Comment: In my img tag have acondition <img id="mainImage" src="{{imageVisible ? droppedImage: firtsImageToBind}}" class="imagepics" alt="loading..." />

Comment: By *not working*, you mean your image doesn't show correctly? I think there may be some error with your base64 data. I tried to decode your data using an online *base64 to image* service, but your image can't show. Please try:  http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter